# React-select: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created component (*working 100% fully*) and after moving it to new directory, after clicking on Select component (should list all options but crashes) from [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select), I am getting:

```
manage-pois.js?v=1523440002:34563 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of null
    at Select.componentDidUpdate (manage-pois.js?v=1523440002:34563)
    at commitLifeCycles (manage-pois.js?v=1523440002:16708)
    at commitAllLifeCycles (manage-pois.js?v=1523440002:17876)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (manage-pois.js?v=1523440002:8472)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (manage-pois.js?v=1523440002:8511)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (manage-pois.js?v=1523440002:8368)
    at commitRoot (manage-pois.js?v=1523440002:17980)
    at performWorkOnRoot (manage-pois.js?v=1523440002:18947)
    at performWork (manage-pois.js?v=1523440002:18897)
    at batchedUpdates (manage-pois.js?v=1523440002:19016)
```

And here is my code where I am rendering Select field:

```
 renderSelectCountry() {
        const {countries} = this.state;
        let options = countries ? countries.map((country) => {
            return {value: country.id, label: country.title};
        }) : [];
        return <Select
            value={this.state.countryId}
            placeholder='Country*'
            onChange={(e) => {
                this.setState({countryId: e ? e.value : ''})
            }}
            options={options}
            style={{marginBottom: '0px'}}
        />
    }
```

Comment: The renderSelectCountry method doesn't contain the point where your code breaks. It seems like in some part of the code you are trying to get the `offsetTop` of an element that is still not present in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

The `<Select>` component tries to get the `offsetTop` property from the DOM element that represents the selected option. It seems that for some reason that option has no DOM node mounted.

I created a [minimal codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/v0zq76wp33) with your code and it seems to work.

The problem likely is not in the code you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. You probably installed and imported `Select` from `react-select-2`. But you should use `react-select` (with no `-2`).

I had the same problem. Using `react-select` made everything work.